# Pattern matcher para formatear números de teléfono españoles

Tags: java, string, regex

Tengo una lista para números de teléfono móvil validados que debo mostrar de una misma manera:

El formato deseado es: `+34 666 111 222`

```
String telefonos = 
            "666444555,
             666-444-555,
             666 44 45 55,
             666-44-45-55,
             +34666555444,
             0034666555444";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(""); // aqui es donde me clavo.
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(telefonos);

while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Salida esperada:

```
+34 666 444 555
+34 666 444 555
+34 666 444 555
+34 666 444 555
+34 666 555 444
+34 666 555 444
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Prueba la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^(0034|\+34)?(\d\d\d)-? ?(\d\d)-? ?(\d)-? ?(\d)-? ?(\d\d)$
```

[image: regex]

Si planeas utilizar esta expresión de manera frecuente, es recomendable utilizar una constante para evitar recompilar la expresión cada vez, es decir:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("^(0034|\\+34)?(\\d\\d\\d)-? ?(\\d\\d)-? ?(\\d)-? ?(\\d)-? ?(\\d\\d)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "666444555\n666-444-555\n666 44 45 55\n666-44-45-55\n+34666555444\n0034666555444";

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceAll("+34 $2 $3$4 $5$6")
    );  
}
```

Salida:

```
+34 666 444 555
+34 666 444 555
+34 666 444 555
+34 666 444 555
+34 666 555 444
+34 666 555 444
```

Comment: Qué chulada el gráfico, ¿cómo lo has generado?

Comment: @Konamiman [regexper.com](http://regexper.com/#%5E(0034%7C%5C%2B34)%3F(%5Cd%5Cd%5Cd)-%3F%20%3F(%5Cd%5Cd)-%3F%20%3F(%5Cd)-%3F%20%3F(%5Cd)-%3F%20%3F(%5Cd%5Cd)%24)

Comment: @Konamiman tambien podes recortar la exp regular a algo como: `^(0034|\+34)?(\d{3})-? ?(\d{2})-? ?(\d)-? ?(\d)-? ?(\d{2})$`

Comment: @Konamiman super currado, me has ahorrado algún tiempo. Aporto mi granito simplificandola un poco más: ^(0034|\+34)?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{2})[- ]?(\d)[- ]?(\d)[- ]?(\d{2})$

Answer (score 14):

Lo mismo que en la otra pregunta, te recomiendo usar `libphonenumber` (la [librería de Google](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) para validar números telefónicos). Tiene muchas ventajas comparado con hacer tu propia implementación, por ejemplo que no tienes que mantenerlo tú y que te da el número en formato internacional, no importando cómo lo ingrese el usuario.

Un ejemplo de cómo se usa es:

```
String number = "666444555"
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
  PhoneNumber number = phoneUtil.parse(number, "ES");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

Ahora hay una serie de métodos pero el más importante sería:

```
boolean isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(number); // retorna true
```

**Acá siempre vas a poder tener el formato internacional que deseas:**

```
System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(number, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL));
```

**Por supuesto, recomiendo siempre que hagas la pregunta de si es válido o no el número antes de preguntar por su formato internacional.**

Para ver un **demo** [puedes ir acá](http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/).

Comment: creo que tu respuesta es lo que el busca con esto -> System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(number, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL));

Comment: muestra cualquier numero en el formato +xx xxx xxx xxx? si es asi es lo que el busca

Comment: Sí, es exactamente lo que muestra, puedes ver el demo en el enlace que puse, el cual repito ahora: http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/

Comment: borrare la mia porque yo entendi mal crei que solo queria los que tenian el formato +xx xxx xxx xxx, por otro lado no sabia que usted habia respondido a algo similar en otro post saludos

Comment: tu respuesta es buena, si él decide no usar librerías de terceros entonces la tuya es la solución que busca.

Comment: pues ahora me dejas que no se si dejarla, porque quizas le sirva a alguien creo que la dejare pero pondre que solo es para este formato +xx xxx xxx xxx tu que crees?

Comment: Leyendo las dos preguntas me confundo un poco, según lo que te comentó @Jordi no es lo que necesita aunque yo pensé que sí.